# matlab matrices of different sizes (indexing, for loop, and bsxfun)

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, bsxfun

I have two matrices of different sizes. Let's just define matrix {a} as a(1:10) <10 x 1> and matrix {b} as b(6:10) <5 x 1>. I need a for loop or equivalent (bsxfun) which gets the difference between matrix {a} and {b}, the code will iterate based on the size of matrix {b}. For example, the first value of matrix {a} is 1, the code will get the difference of all of matrix {b} values. So, it will run a total of 5 times. The next value of matrix {a} is 2, the code will iterate 5 times. The code will iterate until the end of matrix {a} which is value 10.

If you can could you write both a for loop without bsxfun and one with and explain how you indexed the values. Also, just for my edification, instead of two matrices, how would the code change if there were N matrices (N>2)?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want `a` and `b` to be row vectors, say `a = 1:10` and `b = 6:10`, or column vectors, say `a = [ 1:10 ]'` and `b = [ 1:10 ]'`? Other matter is that `length(5:10)` is `6`, not `5` as in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a loop solution and a `repmat` solution.

% Define some example data.

**Edit:** `a` and `b` are column vectors, not row vectors.

```
a = [ 1:10 ]';
```

`b =  [ 6:10 ]';` % `5:10` has vertical size of 6, not 5, so to match the question `6:10` is used.

First, the very basic loop solution: loop through all `aIndex`,`bIndex` pairs, subtract the difference of elements addressed by `aIndex` and `bIndex` and store the result in `LoopDifferenceMatrix(aIndex, bIndex)`.

```
for aIndex = 1:size(a,1)
    for bIndex = 1:size(b,1)
        LoopDifferenceMatrix(aIndex, bIndex) = a(aIndex) - b(bIndex);
    end
end
```

This is an alternative `repmat` solution. Replicate `a` horizontally by using `repmat` so that its horizontal size matches `size(b,1)` (the horizontal size of `b`). Then replicate transposed `b` vertically by using `repmat` so that its vertical size matches `size(a,1)` (the original horizontal size of `a`). Subtract replicated `a` from replicated `b` and store the result in `DifferenceMatrix`.

```
DifferenceMatrix = repmat(a, 1, size(b,1)) - repmat(b', size(a,1), 1);

DifferenceMatrix =
-5    -6    -7    -8    -9
-4    -5    -6    -7    -8
-3    -4    -5    -6    -7
-2    -3    -4    -5    -6
-1    -2    -3    -4    -5
 0    -1    -2    -3    -4
 1     0    -1    -2    -3
 2     1     0    -1    -2
 3     2     1     0    -1
 4     3     2     1     0 

isequal(DifferenceMatrix, LoopDifferenceMatrix)
ans =
1
```

Comment: The `bsxfun` solution is: `DifferenceMatrix=bsxfun(@minus,a,b')`

Comment: @jonas thanks for pointing out the bsxfun. The bsxfun looks to be much more efficient than repmat.

Comment: @BernardUntalanJr.: It's also quite a bit faster. Also, if nrz's answer was helpful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
a = 1:10;
b = 6:10;
c = zeros(length(b),length(a));
d = zeros(length(b),length(a));

for n = 1:length(b)
    c(n,:) = bsxfun(@minus,a,b(n));
    d(n,:) = a - b(n);
end
```

As for how to do it with N matrices you would have to specify what you want to do with the N'th matrix.

Comment: With the code you've written, what would change if instead of two matrices, there are three. The third matrix (e) is (1:15) and it is multiplied by matrix (d) for the length of matrix (e).